# Magento and Google Sitemap auto generation weekly instead of daily

Tags: magento, sitemap

My Google sitemap was originally setup to auto generate daily but it was causing quite a load on the server so I changed the settings in the Magento admin (System > Configuration > Google Sitemap > Generation Settings (weekly) for it to run weekly. The sitemap still generates on a daily basis. Is there something I'm missing or need to change?

Answer (score 1):

I am hunting the same issue.

It looks like there is a bug in `Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Backend_Sitemap_Cron::_afterSave`

Line 45 reads `$frequncy = $this->getData('groups/generate/frequency/value');`

and should read `$frequncy = $this->getData('groups/generate/fields/frequency/value');`

I just tryied this and it worked correctly on each frequency option

Explanation:

When you save the sitemap configuration, this method is called to recalculate the cron expression for sitemap generation which is then read by the cron module to schedule and later run the tasks. On line 57 and 59 it's trying to determine if the frequency is Weekly or Monthly otherwise, its Daily. Since the value being read originally is wrong, it always defaults to daily.

Also the variable should probably be named `$frequency` instead of `$frequncy`

Comment: I already filed a bug report in Magento2 repository and it was acknowledged as a bug

Answer (score 0):

**1. Configuration scope**

Check you configured the sitemap generation frequency in the right scope (default, website or storefront) and the other configuration scopes do not have other values.

**2. Cron scheduling settings**

Maybe unlikely, but possibly there might still be some cron tasks scheduled. The settings for this can be found under `Admin > System > Configuration > System > Cron`. Though you'd have to set those values pretty high. I believe the defaults (or at least sane) values are 15 / 20 / 15 / 10 / 60 / 600.

**3. Cache? / Bugs**

Another issue, as always with Magento, might be cache, clear the cache (sounds unlikely to me too).

I do not know of any problems relating to this system, nor other things you might be able to do to fix this.

**4. Debugging**

The frequency option depends on a backend model to implement an `_afterSave()` method to handle the option. What it does is figure out the selected frequency / times and it makes a string that can be used for the cron configuration. It then saves this in `core_config_data`.

To debug the aftersave function (to check why it is maybe not saving correcty) you will need to have the following class:
`Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Backend_Sitemap_Cron`

To check if the value is properly saved in the database you need to search for the following path:
`crontab/jobs/sitemap_generate/schedule/cron_expr`

If you edit the database directly it will be overridden next time you save the sitemap generation settings.

**Other**

Next to that I can recommend this plugin to inspect the cron schedule table in the database. All it does is read the data in there (and offer some other neat little features) but it can be fairly usefull if you're not very familiar with the Magento code / database architecture.
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aoe-scheduler.html

Comment: Thanks, I've double checked points 1 and 2 and they are all as they should be, I've emptied the cache a few times and double checked compilation is disabled too. Would file permissions be a problem as we did have a previous issue related to file ownership not being able to create cache files. The module looks good, I'll download that now and install.

Comment: The module is really good - It is showing the sitemap_generation cron to be at 0 3 * * * which is 3am every day. Do you know where this specific value stored because I could edit the database directly?

Comment: @Gavin I added another option which allows you to debug it a bit further.

Comment: Thanks. The database entry is the same as what is getting reported 0 3 * * * in the shcedule module so there must be something wrong with the mechanism when it is getting changed via the admin. Do you offer any Magento services for supporting things like this? my email is in my profile